# How to read the value from kubernetes secret in python application and set them as environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables, azure-blob-storage, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to get values from kubernetes secret in my python application as environment variables, I see that secrets are created as separate files and mounted on a specific path(in my case I mount them on etc/secrets/azure-bs. There are five secret files namely

1. accessKeyId
2. bucket.properties
3. storageAccount
4. key.json
5. bucketName.

Now bucket.properties has some key value pairs. There is a property_source parser that is used in the application and it is abstracted from my team. This usually parses secret values. I am however only able to parse bucket.properties since it has key value pairs. I want to be able to read contents from these other files and store them as environment variables. I am not sure how to go about that. The contents in these other files is not in the format of "key=value", instead they key is the filename itself and the value is the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without other details on your question, i can tell you that you can surely create env vars from secrets

```yaml
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
    name: mysecret
```

or

```yaml
env:
  - name: SECRET_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: othersecret
        key: username
```

More details here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/